# Android: How to create an alarm in an AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, widget, alarm

my widget should refresh its textviews every day at 0:00. In the widget_provider.xml I set `android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"` but I read that the minimum update period is 30 minutes and I have to use alarmManager for this. So i want an alarm that triggers the refresh every day at 0:00. UpdateService.class handles the refreshing (setting texts for textviews based on date. The class is just not called until around half an hour after midnight)

In the `public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)` method I am using this code:

```
 Intent intentN = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

In the third line of the copied cut Eclipse says:

```
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type HelloWidget
```

HelloWidget is the name of the AppWidgetProvider.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```